# ImportError: No module named 'debconf' dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common

Tags: debconf

I get this error message...and occurs everytime when I try to upgrade my system.. I am on 16.04 :( please I am a noob...

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168) ...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 26, in <module>

    import debconf

ImportError: No module named 'debconf'

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer:
 flashplugin-installer depends on update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package flashplugin-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

                                Errors were encountered while processing:

 update-notifier-common

 flashplugin-installer

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall corresponding packages with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install debconf python3-debian python3-apt update-manager-core update-notifier-common --reinstall
```